# UV unwrapping instanced geometry node setup

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I'm attempting to unwrap this geometry node setup such that all of the upright faces are unwrapped on one single uv island.

My setup:

[image: geometry node setup]

My current UVs:

[image: current UVs]

I'm running into a couple problems and I'm wondering what the best way to create UVs such that the UVs are projected from a top view. The project UVs modifier won't work, it just makes the texture pink instead of having a uv texture.